# Job Scheduler run job whenever there is available network?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, job-scheduling, periodic-task, android-jobscheduler

I'm using the code below to schedule a job to run when there is internet but it only runs once, I would like it to run whenever there is an available network. Is this possible?

I tried making the job periodic and adding a network constraint thinking that it will sleep and awake whenever a period has passed and check for available network, if there is an available network then it will execute the job, else it will go back to sleep mode but I didn't get the wanted behaviour since the job runs all the time whenever the period is up (as if there is no network constraint)

**This is the scheduling code**

```
mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler)
                getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );

        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder( 1,
                new ComponentName( getPackageName(),
                        JobSchedulerService.class.getName() ) );

       // builder.setPeriodic( 3000 );

        builder.setPersisted(true);
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
        mJobScheduler.schedule( builder.build() );
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use Firebase scheduler and its API, like reported on their [README](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android), using  proper `Constraint` (I guess value could be ON_ANY_NETWORK)

```
 .setConstraints(
    // only run on an unmetered network
    Constraint.ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK,
    // only run when the device is charging
    Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING
)
```

The Broadcast solution wouldn't work, at least not in Android 8, because of new [background service limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html)

Answer (score -1):

### OUTDATED ANSWER

You could register [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that would listen for changes on the network (available/unavailable) and then execute your task or schedule a job with [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)

You will have to add a [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) filter to your [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) like so:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
getActivity().registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, filter);
```

And implement your [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) something like that:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null)
    {             
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (ni != null && ni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
        {
            // conected
        }
        else if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE))
        {
            // not connected
        }
    }
}
```